Every von Neumann Algebra is a direct sum of $\sigma$-finite von Neumann Algebras?
Every von Neumann Algebra is a direct sum of $\sigma$-finite von Neumann Algebras.
I want to prove that via the following results, c.f. 5.5.15 Proposition and 5.5.9 Proposition of Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras, by Kadison:

In a von Neumann algebra, every cyclic projection is $\sigma$-finite.

Each projection in a von Neumann algebra is the union of an orthogonal family of cyclic projections in it.


Now, we can decompose the identity projection $I=\sum_{j\in J}E_j$, and write the von Neumann algebra $\mathcal M$ as $\bigoplus_{j\in J}\mathcal M_{E_j}$.

Your proof is wrong. To write $\mathcal{M}$ as a direct sum, you need $E_j$ to be central projections (as otherwise there can be off-diagonal entries), which may not be the case.
In fact, the result is wrong: $\mathbb{B}(\ell^2(I))$ where $I$ is an uncountable index set is not $\sigma$-finite, and it cannot be written as a (nontrivial) direct sum at all as it is a factor.
